# TFS 2017 deploying to target machine: Agent running under highly privileged account Vs. custom environment variables to store user/pass

Tags: tfs, release-management

According [security recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/infrastructure?view=azure-devops#use-low-privileged-accounts-to-run-agents) using service accounts with privileged access to target machines should be avoided since adversaries can run a compromised release definition on agent getting access to this target machine.

Therefore, I assume that the only (safe) alternative to have highly privileged access to target machine when deploying (In TFS 2017 at least) is to store admin user and pass in custom environment variables and provide it to the task/command which runs the deployment. (let me know if there are any other alternatives available)

I understand that to protect the user & password stored on the environment, the access to it should be restricted to those users who should create release definitions for deploying on the target machine, on this way nobody except them could do it:

[image: environment security]

If you restrict the access to the "privileged agent" (on Agent queues section) only to those users who should create release definitions for deploying on the target machine, nobody except them could do it:

[image: Agent Queues permissions]

So, what´s the risk in using the second option?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set [Release permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#release-permissions) to restrict who can create releases or edit release pipeline, to protect the deployment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cece Dong, but my question was not related to the way of securizing the release definition, but the reason why using a highly privileged service account with permission to deploy (using integrated auth) to a target machine is not a good practice, since you can securize the "privileged agent" on the same way you securize user and password stored as environment custom variables. Both cases allow (as you can see in my screenshots) to restrict the people who is able to acces to the resource.

Comment: Some users who have top level permission (for example, project collection admin) also can use this agent pool. And if someone add other users to this group, they can also do the deployment. It's not good to control the access.

Comment: Good point. Indeed it seems that the permissions in Agent queues are hardcoded for Team Project Collection Admins (no way of restrict access). Anyway, in our organization (and so many others, I guess) this is not a problem since belonging to this group is very restricted. Any other security consideration that could affect to this approach? (to give permissions to the service account and not having multiple users and passwords stored in custom variables are very convenient in our case)

Comment: If this is the case, you can try running the agent with permission.